How to show on a line chart in PowerBI the sum of items that are in a specific status on each date?
I have a table Items with their current status.
And I also a history of their status change (table StatusChanges)
Each status change has ChangeDate and UntilDate.
They are related by ItemId
I want to show a line chart with the number of issues in a specific status on each date of the chart (daily, for instance), so that with a slider (dates from-to) I can select the date range for the line chart.
So far I've been capturing that value and adding it to a table in my PowerBI file - good, values as expected.

Manual values - (May 27th 153 items)
But I'm trying to automate that step and I can't figure out how to show the correct line chart. I've tried several ways and nothing works.

Auto values - (May 27th 279 items)
Issues table:
let
    Origen = Sql.Database("myserver", "mydatabase"),
    dbo_Issues = Origen{[Schema="myschema",Item="Issues"]}[Data],
    #"Columna duplicada" = Table.DuplicateColumn(dbo_Issues, "CreatedDate", "CreatedDate - Copia"),
    #"Tipo cambiado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Columna duplicada",{{"CreatedDate - Copia", type date}}),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo cambiado",{{"CreatedDate - Copia", "CreatedDate_NoTime"}})
in
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado"

StatusChanges table:
let
    Origen = Sql.Database("myserver", "mydatabase"),
    dbo_StatusChanges = Origen{[Schema="myschema",Item="StatusChanges"]}[Data],
    #"Columna duplicada" = Table.DuplicateColumn(dbo_StatusChanges, "ChangeDate", "ChangeDate - Copia"),
    #"Tipo cambiado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Columna duplicada",{{"ChangeDate - Copia", type date}}),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo cambiado",{{"ChangeDate - Copia", "ChangeDate_NoTime"}}),
    #"Columna duplicada1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado", "UntilDate", "UntilDate - Copia"),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Columna duplicada1",{{"UntilDate - Copia", "UntilDate_NoTime"}}),
    #"Fecha extraída" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado1",{{"UntilDate_NoTime", DateTime.Date, type date}})
    // #"Personalizada agregada" = Table.AddColumn(#"Fecha extraída", "ListOfDates", each List.Dates([ChangeDate_NoTime], Duration.Days((if [UntilDate_NoTime] = null then Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) else [UntilDate_NoTime]) - [ChangeDate_NoTime]) + 1, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))),
    // #"Se expandió ListOfDates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Personalizada agregada", "ListOfDates"),
    // #"Filas filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Se expandió ListOfDates", each ([ToStatus] = "Blocked" or [ToStatus] = "En curso" or [ToStatus] = "FOR TESTING" or [ToStatus] = "In Progress" or [ToStatus] = "Parado" or [ToStatus] = "Parking" or [ToStatus] = "Paused" or [ToStatus] = "READY" or [ToStatus] = "Review" or [ToStatus] = "Test" or [ToStatus] = "ToRelease")),
    // #"Columnas con nombre cambiado2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filas filtradas",{{"ListOfDates", "Date"}})
in
    // #"Columnas con nombre cambiado2"
    #"Fecha extraída"

Status list table:
let
    Origen = Sql.Database("myserver", "mydatabase"),
    dbo_StatusList = Origen{[Schema="myschema",Item="StatusList"]}[Data]
in
    dbo_StatusList


Hope people around here can share their expertise with me.
Thanks a lot in advance.
